# Taking the space out of the li ul class

Tags: html, css

I am trying to edit this slide show, but I don't know how to take the space out of the images, I want minimum space.

Here is the slider:

http://littleladyenterprises.com/wp-content/themes/blackchic/FullWidthImageSlider/

and here is the CSS:

http://littleladyenterprises.com/wp-content/themes/blackchic/FullWidthImageSlider/css/component.css

How do I get the images to align next to each other without the space?

Comment: and what have you tried? Did you try to play with the CSS in Developer Console / Firebug ?

Comment: i dont know how to use firebug, but i did look for answeres and found something that says add `float:left;` and add `display:block;` to the css, but the images still are spaced out i don't know what to do here @ShivanRaptor

Comment: Also it is aligned before the `.js` loads up

Answer (score 0):

Change `<li style="width:20%">` to just `<li>` for every listitem, what is happening currently is that you have set the `width` of the `ul` to `500%`, and the `width` of the `li`'s inside it to `20%` of that `500%`. This means that every `li` will be `20%` of `500%`, this ends up looking similar to setting the `width` of both the `ul` and the `li`'s inside it to `100%`. The difference with a setup like that is that currently there is enough space inside the `500%` wide `ul` for all the `li`'s to float left, instead of having them all display under each other, which will happen if you set the `width` of both the `ul` and the `li`'s inside it to `100%`

It is not entirely clear what you are trying to achieve, but getting rid of the `width` set on the `li`'s will definitely get rid of the extra white space to the right of the image.

Setting `display: block;` on the image, as you mentioned in the comments to your question, is a good idea, but it is unrelated to the white space currently visible to the right of your image. It does get rid of some white space which is added by the browser around inline elements, for images this usually means a few pixels of white space under the image.

Comment: There is no `<li style="width:20%">` where did you see this

Comment: I see that using [FireBug](http://www.getfirebug.com), it must be added by the JavaScript for the slider then. I think what is happening is that the JavaScript decides - based on the number of slides - how wide each slide should be to make it fill the whole screen. Maybe there is a setting in the slider plugin you are using to make it behave differently.

Comment: It looks like you are using a jQuery plugin named "Full Width image slider", so chances are that there is no such setting. It looks like you don't have the right plugin for the job. You could just fill each `li` element up with images, there won't be any space between the images that are in the same `li` element. But this does kind of does make the "Full Width image slider" lose its dynamicness, as users with smaller screen won't be able to see all the images anymore.

Answer (score 0):

Just add width and text-align property to container class like this,

```
 .container{
   margin: 0 auto; /* for center align*/
   text-align: center;
   width: 686px;

 }
```